# Goal: Is it possible to integrate an Asp.Net website with Joomla CMS

Tags: asp.net, joomla

I have an asp.net application which is purely build using C#, CSS, Javascript. Now i need to integrate my application with joomla cms.

```
         **Is it possible to integrate an Asp.Net website with Joomla CMS**
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you want to integrate? Users? Content? You need to give more information.

Comment: You definitely need to give more information on what you mean by "integrate", that's a very broad term.

Comment: My aim is to manage my whole website with jooomla.. is this possible??

Comment: I want to integrate my whole website including the Content.Is this possible??

Comment: As others have said 'integrate' is a very broad term. It also comes down to whether or not your integrating joomla with .net or .net with joomla. In a simple way you could always load the one site within an iframe on the other but without any details....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and depending on what you are trying to "integrate" it might be fairly easy to do. First, you will need to get ChronoForms and ChronoConnectivity. Without having any more details here is what you would need to do -

1. Put the Joomla DB in the same database. By default Joomla uses the prefix jos_ for its database tables so this should not pose any issues. This will make it easy to access the tables of your application within Joomla.
2. Next you will need to create a form that has a field for each corresponding field in the table you want to edit. You will need one form for each table.
3. Using ChronoConnectivity you then associate the form with the table in the database.

This is pretty basic but it will give you the ability to edit any table in the same database that Joomla is installed in. You may have to get a little trickier to make it work well, but you can insert additional code in both ChoronForms and ChronoConnectivity as needed.

That would probably be the fastest and easiest way to do a simple integration.